# How to update the same column for multiple rows in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I need to update all the records in the `Client` table if `address_1` is blank, but `address_2` is not. In those cases I want to move `address_2` into `address_1`. Here is my query so far:

```
UPDATE Client SET Address_1 = 'address1', address_2 = ''
WHERE client_id = 'client_id'
```

But instead of passing in `client_id`, I want to update every record.

Comment: Leave out the `where` criteria perhaps -- that will update the entire table?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to update our table where address 1 is blank but address 2 is not and move the adress 2 to address 1

Comment: `Update Client Set Address_1 = address_2, address_2 = '' where Address_1 = '' and address_2 <> ''`

Comment: I ended up extracting the data onto excel and writing the script there thanks

Comment: @Lashane . . . You should make your comment an answer.

Comment: Added question clarification from comments and reworded for readability. Also improved code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you need is

```
UPDATE client SET address_1 = address_2, address_2 = ''
WHERE address_1 = '' AND address_2 != ''
```

In the `WHERE`, it finds all the problem rows, then it moves `address_2` to `address_1` and blanks out `address_2`

**Note**: Make sure you're not confusing empty string `''` with `NULL`. In DB2, those are not the same. If your values are actually `NULL`, your query would need to be:

```
UPDATE client SET address_1 = address_2, address_2 = NULL
WHERE address_1 IS NULL AND address_2 IS NOT NULL
```